# http:// to https://www redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `http://`  to `https://www`. Now it is redirecting `https://` then `https://www`

I am using siteground I tried many answers given on StackOverflow.

Example of codes I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect redirection

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

the redirect rules mentioned here is perfect but will work only if you disable server-side redirect.

In your siteground hosting account
Goto site tools > Security > HTTPS enforce and disable it

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer here, could you please be clear which site and options are you mentioning here? To make it more clear. Kindly do add more details in your answer, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks i updated. your redirect is almost perfect but if enter `http://www` it redirects to `https://` then `https://www`

Comment: sure but `Goto site tools > Security > HTTPS ` is not clear on which tool etc we are doing this not clear, so only I have asked here, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You were close you need not to use `OR` condition after checking https condition, could you please try following. Following rules should apply https to a non `http` url with/without `www`.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Cloudflare CDN` or any other proxy server then you will need to match against `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}`  variable to detect the URL scheme.
You can use the following rule that redirects `http` and `https-noWWW`  to `https://www` in a single request :

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} http$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this rule.